# Generate KML file on iPhone

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, kml

In my app I have to draw route between user location and destination location in `MKMapView` with help of `MKAnnotation` and `MKOverlay` classes. I had gone through the `KMLViewer` sample code from Apple in there they mentioned to create KML file outside the programming steps, but I need KML file generation inside iPhone app programming.

Is it possible? And I need help on doing that..

**Steps to get KML file manually**

The process to obtain a KML is as follows:

- Go to: "http://maps.google.com/"
- Click "Get Directions" link
- Type in the start and destination addresses
  (for example)
  **Start** = 451 University Avenue, Palo Alto, CA 94301
  **Destination** = #1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014
- Modify the route as you wish.
- Click the "Link" to this page link.
- Copy the email/IM link.
- Paste the link back into your Safari's address bar.
- Add `&output=kml` to the end of the URL and press the enter key.
- The KML file will be downloaded to your Downloads folder.

but I need this to be done programmatically...

Answer (score 3):

KML is just XML and there are various methods for generating XML files in Cocoa, e.g. using [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/).

The KML format is documented here: http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html.

Comment: Thanks for clearing some points on my questions, The KML file which i'm creating from [map.google.com](http://map.google.com) is simple by **Get Direction** methods, are you suggesting me to use get direction api from google map to generate KML or is there any other ways to get KML from google map as simple by giving two locations names.

Comment: The Directions API doesn't provide data in the KML format. You can get JSON or a custom XML format. Using the latter, it should be relatively easy to adapt the parser in Apple's sample code. See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#XML

Comment: Yes omz, that is what i'm going to do now, but i need KML output response instead of JSON/XML. KMLParser Class methods do most of the work and returns only two arrays that are **overlays** for drawing route and **points** for annotations. @omz i'm searching for class libraries which have do the KML file generation from XML response or to get the KML file directly from the [map.google.com](http://map.google.com) programmatically.

Comment: hi karthik, did you end up solving this?  what did you end up doing?  I am trying to do the same thing