# create and use google's kml file programmatically in xcode iphone

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, xcode4.2, download, kml

I am working on google maps and wanted to know if we can create the kml file and download it and use it in our code,I referred to **sample KMLViewer by apple** but it instruct you to open browser and manually do it,

Is there any way i can download it and use  in my app.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a solution on this as well.  This SO question is relevant:  [Generate KML file within iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813963/generate-kml-file-within-iphone-app) -- I think the way to do it is to use the Directions API from Google:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/